# How to print to the REPL window in a Ring handler?

Tags: clojure, ring, ccw

```
(defn app [request]
  (println "test")
  {:body "Hello World"})

(defonce server (run-jetty #'app {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

`println` doesn't seem to work in a handler. How do I write to the REPL window?

I'm using eclipse with counterclockwise.

EDIT: This looks like [nrepl issue](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el/issues/83). `(future (println "foo"))` is fine, but no output with `(.start (Thread. #(println "foo")))`.

Answer (score 6):

`println` doesn't write to output directly, rather it buffers the output and flush it later.
You can try `(.println System/out "test")`

Answer (score 2):

You can find the outputin the `*nrepl-server ...*` buffer for your project. In CIDER, this buffer is hidden. You can find it with `C-x C-b` though.